# Detect color type from color code via props and render jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Please I need to be able to display a color in a table cell. I have the code stored in mongodb along with the description. I need a library that can detect whether rgb or hex from the color code supplied through props and render it.

[image]

As shown above I want the color field to show the color as specified in the code field. Even if I don't get a library that detect the color, I appreciate. I don't mind doing some heavy lifting. As at now this is what my code looks like.

```
const ColorList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getColors(user?.refreshToken));
  }, [dispatch]);
  const { colors } = useSelector((state) => state.color);
  return (
    <div className="container-xxl">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <table className="table table-striped table-hover table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Code</th>
                <th scope="col">Color</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {colors.map(({ color, name }, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                  <td>{name}</td>
                  <td>{color}</td>
                  <td>
                    <span
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: { color },
                        width: "6px",
                        height: "2px",
                      }}
                    ></span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Make the `span` a `div` and give some dimension. You might be happy.

Comment: Its amazing I can seem to find a library to display a color from code

Comment: @code46 are you all set?

Comment: @TulaMagar No please. I can't seem to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you place the value in the `backgroundColor`. You have the choice to store color code like the array or single string (`"217,22,3"` or use code value `rbg(217,22,3)`) and later split the string

updated version:

```
import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
  const colors = [{ name: "name", code: "rgb(217,22,3)", color: [217, 22, 3] }];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table className="table table-striped table-hover table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Code</th>
            <th scope="col">Color</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {colors.map((color, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
              <td>{color.name}</td>
              <td>{color.code}</td>
              <td>
                <span
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: `rgb(${color.color[0]}, ${color.color[1]}, ${color.color[2]})`,
                    display: "inline-block", // span needs a content to have non zero height
                    width: "6px",
                    height: "10px"
                  }}
                ></span>
                <div
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: `rgb(${color.color[0]}, ${color.color[1]}, ${color.color[2]})`,
                    width: "6px",
                    height: "10px"
                  }}
                ></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can find the live code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/colortest-8w777x?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I have done all that you said but no results. I have destructured the variables from color object and placed them in curly braces but still. So there is no library that can display colors from code??

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate the help. I made use of this package https://yarnpkg.com/package/color to covert the color to array and took care of the rest.. Gratitude